# How to check calendar subscribed ics feed programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icalendar

When you try to subscribe already subscribed ics feed it gives:

[image: alert]

I tried to subscribed with this code:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "webcal://mlb.am/tix/yankees_schedule_full")!)
```

I want to check programmatically if already subscribed for ics feed or not so i can prevent this alert.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly took 2 weeks to find the solution.

```
   func checkICS() {
   let eventStrore = EKEventStore()
   eventStrore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) { (granted, error) -> Void in

   let allCalendars = eventStrore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)

   for currentCal : EKCalendar in allCalendars {
                if (currentCal.type == EKCalendarType.Subscription && currentCal.title == "<Your ICS String>") {
                    print("Already Subscribed")
                    flag = true
                }
            }
            if (flag == false) {
                self.addICSSubscription()
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: How to add .ics file from app to icalendar whether .ics file in app document directory.

Comment: I didn’t try in my code but this might help you

let path = mainBundle.pathForResource("test", ofType: "ics")
        let url = NSURL(string: path!)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)